# Sending JSON POST request in VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, rest, api

I have the following JSON POST sample code which I am trying to convert to VBA for Excel:

```
POST /services/shipper/orders HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0
Host: qa.etowertech.com
X-WallTech-Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2018 21:20:27 GMT
Authorization: WallTech test5AdbzO5OEeOpvgAVXUFE0A:79db9e5OEeOpvgAVXUFWSD
```

Here is the code I came up with:

```
With JsonHTTP
             .Open "POST", "http://qa.towertech.com/services/shipper/orders", False
             .setRequestHeader "RequestName", "application/json"
             .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
             .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla 5.0"
             .setRequestHeader "Host", "qa.etowertech.com"
             .setRequestHeader "X-WallTech-Date", "Tue, 06 Jan 2018 21:20:27 GMT"
             .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "WallTech test5AdbzO5OEeOpvgAVXUFE0A:79db9e5OEeOpvgAVXUFWSD"
             .send (body)
End With
```

I wasn't sure where the `POST /services/shipper/orders HTTP/1.1` input should go

I keep getting this response:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 100004,
      "message": "System internal error"
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

**EDIT:**

The current response I'm getting:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Authorization information is invalid."
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

I just figured I missed out on the Signature (see below instruction) but wasn't sure how to render it and where it goes exactly in the request?

**X-WallTech-Date**

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz
```

**Authorization**

```
WallTech <Access Token>:<Base64 Encoded HMAC SHA-1 Hash>
```

**Signature String**

```
<HTTP Verb> + "\0x000A" + <X-WallTech-Date Header> + "\0x000A" + <Full URL>
```

Comment: Check if this line
`.setRequestHeader "RequestName", "application/json"` be:
`.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"` -- and if the request needs to be sent via HTTPS, not just HTTP --- and if Authorisation header you're sending is correct (server might be expecting the string after WallTech to be base64 encoded). I think /services/shipper/orders should go in the URL (as you've done) so that's the correct, but you should also check if the JSON you're sending in request's body is valid.

Comment: I would also comment out or delete this line from your code/the request you're sending: `X-WallTech-Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2018 21:20:27 GMT`

Comment: `body` is not shown being defined or created.

Comment: @chillin That worked out! I did miscopy the Content-Type for RequestName. Thank you!

Comment: @chillin just edited with an update

Comment: Just to confirm, you have copy-pasted this `WallTech <Access Token>:<Base64 Encoded HMAC SHA-1 Hash>` from some form of API documentation, which explains how to authenticate the request? Similarly, this `<HTTP Verb> + "\0x000A" + <X-WallTech-Date Header> + "\0x000A" + <Full URL>` has also come from somewhere?

Comment: Based on your edit, I think the signature would be something like `"POST" & vbnewline & format(now,"DDD, dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss") & " GMT" & vbnewline & "http://qa.towertech.com/services/shipper/orders"` but you would then need to feed this string to your HMAC SHA1 function, and then feed the output of the HMAC SHA1 function to a base64 encoding function. That output will then be appended to `"WallTech " & YourAPITokenGoesHere & ":" `

Comment: But I think you will need a secret string/key for the HMAC computation -- and an access token to include in the Authorization header. Check with the service/API provider, if you don't already have these credentials. Also, you may need to check if server expects X-WallTech-Date header to be per GMT/UTC. If it does, you may experience authentication issues/expired requests if the timestamp you send is non-GMT.

Comment: @chillin That worked out! I followed these instructions and the request now goes through without a problem. I did send an invalid authentication string (that I sent to a SHA1 function along with a key, but I missed out on the Base64 function which I've now added). The authentication string is now `auth = Base64_HMACSHA1("POST" & Chr(10) & timestamp & Chr(10) & url, key)` and the header is `.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Walltech " & token & ":" & auth` Thanks again, that helped tremendously!

Comment: Excellent, no problem mate.

Comment: @Dan Could you please post an answer then and accept it, just to make the solution clear?

Comment: @omegastripes Yes surely, just posted the answer, hope it makes it all clear!

Comment: How can we do this on postman?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
url = "http://qa.towertech.com/services/shipper/orders"
token = "xxxxxx" ' API token goes here
auth = Base64_HMACSHA1("POST" & Chr(10) & timestamp & Chr(10) & url, key)

With JsonHTTP
             .Open "POST", url, False
             .setRequestHeader "RequestName", "application/json"
             .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
             .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla 5.0"
             .setRequestHeader "Host", "qa.etowertech.com"
             .setRequestHeader "X-WallTech-Date", timestamp
             .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Walltech " & token & ":" & auth
             .send (body)
End With
```

The problem was the secret key was missing from the Base64 function so the auth string was incorrectly encoded

Hope this helps anyone else having the same!