# Issue with sending JSON data from VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel macro to send cell data to a URL using a POST request. I have chosen to format that data using JSON, because there is a lot of it to send. Here is my code for sending the JSON:

```
    Dim jFullDictionary As New Dictionary ' This dictionary contains a Collection
    ...
    Dim JsonURL As String
    JsonURL = "http://myurl.com"
    Dim JsonHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set JsonHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Dim JsonString As String
    JsonString = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jFullDictionary, Whitespace:=3)
    With JsonHTTP
        .Open "POST", JsonURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        .send JsonString ' This is where the program breaks
    End With
```

Every time I run this, I get the error that says (something along the lines of)

```
Run time error: Could not find the resource specified
```

I have already looked at these StackOverflow threads, but I've gotten nowhere:
[Error from VB excel macro code - msxml3.dll -2146697211 The system cannot locate the resource specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726661/error-from-vb-excel-macro-code-msxml3-dll-2146697211-the-system-cannot-locate)

[Sending JSON POST request in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133663/sending-json-post-request-in-vba)

Additionally, I have tried installing Tim Hall's project from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021540/post-json-to-web-in-excel-vba), but the installation doesn't work on my machine (might be because it's a work computer).

The error makes me think that it has something to do with the resources that I have loaded, but I'm not sure. If it's not that, then there is something wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit:
Here is the loop that I use to fill the `jFullDictionary` with my data:

```
    Dim jDictionary As New Dictionary
    Dim jCollection As New Collection
    Dim jFullDictionary As New Dictionary

    For i = 1 To excelRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To excelRange.Columns.Count
            jDictionary("row") = i
            jDictionary("name") = Cells(5, j) ' This assignment is arbitrary
            jDictionary("value") = Cells(i + 1, j) ' so is this
            jCollection.Add jDictionary
            Set jDictionary = Nothing
        Next j
    Next i

    jFullDictionary.Add "parametersList", jCollection
```

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @QHarr I'd be happy to, but wouldn't that require me to create an excel sheet with dummy data? Alternatively, I can just edit the post with the loops that I use to add data to the jFullDictionary?

Comment: Is the url public? And is that the line which is failing? i.e. _.Open "POST", JsonURL, False_

Comment: @QHarr the URL is not public, I am running it from localhost. But that's not the issue. The line that it is failing on is `.send JsonString`

Comment: What is the value of JsonString when it fails? Have you checked it is the value you expected and valid json?

Comment: @QHarr the value of `JsonString` is what I expect it to be when it fails. It's very long, so I can't post it, but it looks like valid JSON code. Let me try running my code with a short JSON string that I know is valid

Comment: @QHarr I just ran it with verified JSON text and I got the same error.

Comment: Try `.send (JsonString)`